# How To Use 'beforeunload' to Capture Iframe Click?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, focus, onbeforeunload

I am trying to build a code that does a request when a cross-origin iframe is clicked and it directs the main window to a new page.

Since it's impossible to directly tap into Iframe click events, I thought of the following conditions as necessary:

- page unload event occurs
- the window is out of focus

Page unload (As far as I know) happens only when the current url is directed to some other url.

Now, this unload could happen by clicking any link. To restrict it to Iframes, I added the condition of window being out of focus.

```
addEventListener('beforeunload',(event) =>{
    if(!(document.hasFocus())){
        // Do Something
    }
});
```

My question is, are their any limitations to this approach? If yes, then please suggest some more conditions to make it as close to reality.

For those of you, who are curious: I want to track clicks on Google AdSense Iframes on my website.

Comment: what do you want to capture here? you can't get much information of the clicked iframe!!

Comment: Yes. I just want some JS to run whenever an iframe is clicked, that's it.

Comment: why do you need to do document.hasFocus() for?

Comment: For knowing when the iframe is clicked. Is there any better way to detect cross-origin iframe click? If the document is NOT focused and the unload event is triggered, it means that the unload event originated from Iframe... Any better approach?

Comment: there isn't unless you block the user to navigate... for example.. when you will bind unload, you can async request and do some thing your own!! but if you don't block the user nagivation then the event won't fire anything or execution will not happen like ajax request will be not send completely

Comment: Aaah, I know that problem of AJAX, and I have figured out the solution to that problem. The solution is to use javascript beacons, read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon